# Under what conditions do waves stay monochromatic?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, acoustics, frequency

Based on my intuition, once light is monochromatic it will stay that way unless you actively try to change its frequency. My intuition stems from the intricate optical laser setups in my lab that sometimes (often?) work with monochromatic light. Sound, on the other hand, seems to change its frequency easily when it interacts with the environment. Again, this is based on intuition so I'm not sure if its true. So my questions are

1. Does light stay monochromatic once it is created?
2. Does sound stay monochromatic once it is created?
3. Why? Under what conditions do waves stay monochromatic?

Comment: Are you asking about the light changing wavelength (which happens every time it enters a medium of refractive index > 1) or are you asking about light of a single wavelength becoming light with a range of wavelengths?

Comment: *Sound, on the other hand, seems to change its wavelength easily when it interacts with the environment.* Please give an example.

Comment: @JohnRennie I guess I meant light with a single *frequency* to be more precise.

Comment: @Farcher I imagine if you play a note of a single frequency and it reverberates in a guitar casing, or in a particular room

Comment: I general a musical instrument cannot produce a sound which contains only one frequency. The webpage [Musical sounds, musical instruments and musical signals](https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/musical-sounds-musical-instruments.html#instruments)  and the links therein. A tuning fork does a reasonable job as any harmonics produced are quickly damped down. So what you might hear with a musical note is the effect of the harmonics dying away?

Answer (score 4):

As long as the operations that act on the waves are *linear* the waves will remain monochromatic.  Nonlinear operators can create additional harmonics (or sub-harmonics). Google 'linearity and harmonics generation'.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection or scattering of waves by a moving object will change the frequency by the Doppler effect. Even if the object isn't moving initially, if the interaction transfers appreciable energy to the object, the frequency will shift (Compton effect). Nonlinear media can produce a variety of frequency changes, including "mixing" where waves of different frequencies combine to produce waves at sum or difference frequencies.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you say that light is less sensitive to this effect because $v$ is usually much smaller than the speed of light, but can be easily in the order of the speed of sound?